# VirtualStringTree - How to make it so that the nodes simply do not have a parent

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I'm trying to move the nodes to the root of the tree so that they do not have a parent

```
Tree.MoveTo(LNodes[i], nil, amAddChildFirst, False);
```

But they are simply deleted! 
How to make it so that the nodes simply do not have a parent?

Comment: What are `LNodes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need

```
Tree.MoveTo( LNodes[i], LNodes[0], amInsertBefore, False);
```